# Use NVIDIA GPUDirect RDMA with nvJPEG

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda, jpeg, nvidia

Is that possible to use [NVIDIA GPIDirect RDMA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html) with [NVIDIA nvJPEG](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvjpeg/index.html)?

From the description of RDMA technology that should be possible but seems nvJPEG interfaces expect only host memory input.

Comment: Do you want to decode or encode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia nvJPEG uses a hybrid approach for JPEG decoding. Some of the code is executed on the CPU, some of it on the GPU.

See especially the decoupled functions https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvjpeg/index.html#nvjpeg-decoupled-decode-api

So, no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nvJPEG for encoding raw data from device memory, with the output in device memory. You could use [nvjpegEncodeImage()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvjpeg/index.html#nvjpeg-encode-image) followed by [nvjpegEncodeRetrieveBitstreamDevice()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvjpeg/index.html#nvjpeg-encode-retrieve-bitstream-device).

Regarding the decoding, you can use the batched API with the *_DEVICE* backends! It allows to pass device pointers